# why is 00 000 added after each assembly (8086) line?

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

An assembly program is converted to binary code and I ran a simple code in emulator for 8086. I excepted the `IP` to be `0004`, instead it had been `0006`.

```
MOV AX,21H
ADD AX,42H
```

I think **IP** should be **0004H**, 0000 FOR *MOV* ,then 0000 to read *21H* ,and same for *ADD* and *42H*.

Whereas in emulator it is:

```
01000: B8 184
01001: 21 003
01002: 00 000 NULL
02003: 05 005
01004: 53 066
01005: 00 000 NULL
```

why is adding 01002 and 01005 to the code?and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because the `ax` register is 16 bits, so the constant is actually 16 bits as well (two bytes). It's just that your constants are so small that you don't notice that the upper byte is always zero.

Try

```
mov ax, 1234h
```

and see whether that is different.